# Draw geom_ribbon parallel to x-intercept when x-asis is date and y-axis is factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have these dataframes

```
set.seed(28100)
myDF <- data.frame(name = factor(sample(c("John","Paul","Ringo","George"),100,replace=TRUE)),
                   date = sample(1:1000,100,replace=TRUE))

periods <- data.frame(first = c(100,500,700),
                      last = c(300,600,900))
```

I want to plot a horizontal line for each name connecting all the observations. Like

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_point(data=myDF, aes(x = date, y = name)) + 
  geom_line(data=myDF, aes(x = date, y = name))
```

[image]

So far so good. Now I want to add a ribbon for each observation of `periods`, the ribbon should be drawn between two x-intercepts set respectively as `first` and `last`, like

```
geom_ribbon(data=periods, aes(xmin=first, xmax=last))
```

which doesn't work.

What I want to obtain is coloring an area correpoding to each period in `periods`. So for the period 100-300, the result should look like

[image]

Comment: I think there is no `xmin` and `xmax` in `geom_ribbon`. And are values in `periods` the `date` of `myDF`?

Comment: Did you mean to type `geom_segment` or maybe `geom_area`?

Comment: @Pascal Yes, the values in `periods` correspond to the date in `myDF`

Comment: Maybe `geom_rect`? Something like `geom_rect(data=periods, aes(ymin = .5, ymax = 4.5, xmin=first, xmax=last))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on aosmith's comment, looks like you can get the effect you want with geom_rect:

[image]

In order to get the transparency that geom_ribbon usually has (which I assume is why you thought of it), set the `alpha` attribute of `geom_rect` to some number less than 1.

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data=myDF, aes(x = date, y = name)) +
     geom_line(data=myDF, aes(x = date, y = name)) +
     geom_rect(data=periods, aes(ymin = .5, ymax = 4.5, xmin=first,
              xmax=last, alpha=.5, fill=c("red", "blue", "green")))
```